# Example for displaying a full page iAd on iPhone

Tags: ios, iad

I know about `ADInterstitialAd`, but there is never enough info in the Apple docs. Can someone provide a full example how to display a full-page iAd on iPhone this work please?

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would vote this down, why don't people want to answer this question? There isn't ANY good examples of this on stack over flow! Why are people afraid to help on this site?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the sample code Apple provides for working with ADInterstitialAd:

[iAdInterstitialSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdInterstitialSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010627)

Comment: Yeah i did, wasn't much help as I said.

Comment: Why, it's a full **sample project** that described and shows you exactly what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH5-SW1) and [Sample App Tutorial](http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.sg/2015/06/interstitial-ads.html)